# OSM Importer of Neo4j with LayerNodeIndex

Tags: neo4j, spatial, openstreetmap

I have been playing with neo4j for a few months now (not so thoroughly, though!).
I have seen the examples of OSMImporter in test cases, and also how to make a WITHIN_DISTANCE_QUERY ( http://structr.org/blog//299fbc8d5d854c78a530793e1555ae77 )
I was wondering, how can someone integrate the above?
Should I modify the source of OSMImporter?

Cheers

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the integration?

Comment: Just to get the POIs defined in OSM file within certain distance from a given lat,lon.

Answer (score 1):

So, you don't need the OSM importer if you are not using OSM files. Just add points from your domain to a layer, just like https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/LayersTest.java#L57

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just thought it was a very common case, so something would have already been implemented regarding POIs in OSM.

Comment: btw, a blog post when you get it working would be most appreciated.